# Decrypting file in C++, which was encrypted with openssl -aes-128-cbc

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to decrypt a file in C++. This file is encrypted with the following command:

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -pass pass:test -in "test.txt" -out "test_enc.txt" -p
```

The console shows the `key=098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6` and `iv=0A9172716AE6428409885B8B829CCB05`.

In C++ I have included the `#include openssl/aes.h` line and try to decrypt with the following code:

```
const char *indata = string.toAscii().constData();

unsigned char outdata[strlen(indata)];

unsigned char ckey[] = "098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6";
    unsigned char ivec[] = "0A9172716AE6428409885B8B829CCB05";

    /* data structure that contains the key itself */
    AES_KEY key;

    /* set the encryption key */
    AES_set_decrypt_key(ckey, 256, &key);

    AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char*) indata, outdata, strlen(indata), &key, ivec, AES_DECRYPT);

    QString result = QString((const char*) outdata);

    return result;
```

The variable outdata contains different value than before encryption with OpenSSL.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: The question is: Why is the output of AES_cbc_encrypt differant to the input of openssl enc... before? Why is the content before the encryption differant to the content after the decryption?

Answer (score 1):

You specify `-aes-128-cbc` as an option on OpenSSL so the key and initialization vector will be **128 bits** long. `openssl` prints these out as **hex strings**, as they would be obfuscated on the console if printed binary.

Therefor you should initialize your `ckey[]` and `ivec[]` as the binary value of the hex strings like this:

```
unsigned char ckey[] = "\x09\x8F\x6B\xCD\x46\x21\xD3\x73\xCA\xDE\x4E\x83\x26\x27\xB4\xF6";
unsigned char ivec[] = "\x0A\x91\x72\x71\x6A\xE6\x42\x84\x09\x88\x5B\x8B\x82\x9C\xCB\x05";
```

and also, use key length **128** instead of **256** in:

```
AES_set_decrypt_key(ckey, 128, &key);
```

Comment: Now, i have after decryption some new characters. I encrypted the string "test" and after decryption the string "ï»¿test" (white 1 space character and 8 tabs behind) is in the new file.

Comment: If above answer solved you problem, then please accept the answer. If you have new problems with a new test, then feel free to create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL creates the key using the password you offer, and also the vector you specified is related to decryption and encryption. Make sure you have the same key and vector while decrypting the text.

Comment: I use the same key and ivec for decryption, which was generated from the openssl enc with password. In that example i changed the password to "test" and not the key/ivac in my decode function.

I think the problem has to do with a differance between the algorithm in openssl and AES_cbc_encrypt.