# OpenSSL EVP API: How to decrypt the encrypted file using a symmetric key file

Tags: openssl, symmetric-key, evp-cipher

Hi I'm working on C on Linux.

I have a query related to symmetric key decryption.

I have generated an symmetric key using the below command.

**openssl rand base64 512 > sym.key**

Using this key (**sym.key**) I have encrypted a file with below command.

**openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in temp.txt -out temp.enc -kfile sym.key**

It has generated an encrypted file **temp.enc**.

Now, I have to use the same key (**sym.key**) with **EVP Decrypt API's** and have to decrypt this encrypted file.

Could any one suggest me a better approach for this.

Here is the code

```
unsigned char* decode (unsigned char *key, int len)
{

   BIO *b64, *bmem;

   char *buffer = (char *)malloc(len);
   memset (buffer, 0, len);

   b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
   bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, len);
   bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

   BIO_read(bmem, buffer, len);

   BIO_free_all(bmem);

    return buffer;
}

void decrypt(char *file_name, char *key_file)
{   

    unsigned char *inbuff = NULL, *outbuff = NULL, *ckey = NULL;
    char *buff = NULL;
    unsigned int flen = 0, outlen2 = 0, outlen1 = 0, klen = 0;

    FILE *fp = NULL, *kfp = NULL;
        unsigned char iv[16] = {};

    fp = fopen (file_name, "r");

    if (NULL == fp)
    {
        printf ("Cannot open file : %s\n", file_name);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    flen = ftell (fp);
    rewind (fp);

    kfp = fopen (key_file, "r");

    if (NULL == kfp)
    {
        printf ("Cannot open file : %s\n", key_file);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek (kfp, 0, SEEK_END);
    klen = ftell (kfp);
    rewind (kfp);

    inbuff = (unsigned char *)malloc(flen);
    outbuff = (unsigned char *)malloc(flen * 2);
    ckey = (unsigned char *)malloc(klen);
    buff = (char *)malloc(klen);

    fread (inbuff, sizeof(char), flen, fp);
    fread (buff, sizeof(char), klen, kfp);

    ckey = decode(buff, klen);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

#if 1
    if (! EVP_DecryptInit (&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ckey, iv))
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        printf ("Error in Init\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (! EVP_DecryptUpdate (&ctx, outbuff, &outlen1, inbuff, flen))
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        printf ("Error in Init\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (! EVP_DecryptFinal (&ctx, outbuff + outlen1, &outlen2))
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        printf ("Error in Init\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
#endif

    free (inbuff);
    free (outbuff);
    free (ckey);
    fclose (fp);
    fclose (kfp);

    printf ("Outbuff:\n %s\n", outbuff);

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting file in C++, which was encrypted with openssl -aes-128-cbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660943/decrypting-file-in-c-which-was-encrypted-with-openssl-aes-128-cbc)

Comment: Hi. I couldn't get  you. Could you brief me little more on your suggestion.

Comment: There are plenty of EVP encryption/decryption examples out there. Like here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption
If you've got more specific question and exemplary code, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

I have already referred to this example. In this as we see they are using **KEY** and **IV** combination keys, which are hard coded.

What exactly my concern is,

I have generated a random key using **rand** option in **openSSL** and saving the result as **sym.key** as shown

**openssl rand base64 512 > sym.key **

Using this key file, I have encrypted a file through command prompt as 
**openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in temp.txt -out temp.enc -kfile sym.key**

Now, using same key file, I have to decrypt the file through any EVP API's.

So could you help me in this.

Comment: If you don't want your key to be hardcoded (which is a great approach) then your program will have to read from a file. I guess you can do that by yourself. Next, you'll have to decode your file from Base64 (which is extensively covered in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288076/doing-base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-openssl-c). Finally, you pass the param to the decryption init function and just follow the rest of the first link.

Comment: Hi tried the below coding. Could you please tell me your comments.
Find the code in the below answer

Comment: You should add your code to your question (edit it) if it's not the final answer, and precise what is the error.

Answer (score 3):

> Using this key (sym.key) I have encrypted a file with below command.
>   
> `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in temp.txt -out temp.enc -kfile sym.key`

Not quite. `openssl enc -kfile` reads the first line, and only the first line, of the file and uses it as the **password**, which is not the same thing as the key. `enc` has three options to enter a password, after which it runs the password with random salt through a **key derivation process to produce the actual key and IV** (for ciphers that use an IV, and AES-CBC does). It then writes a header containing the salt, followed by the ciphertext, to the output file. This is called Password Based Encryption (PBE) and sometimes a Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF).

Depending on what you actually want to do there are two approaches.

## To decrypt the file you have

Read the first line from `sym.key` (excluding the line terminator) as characters, NOT base64, and feed it with the salt from `temp.enc` through `EVP_BytesToKey` something like this:

```
FILE * pwfile = fopen (key_file, "r"); 
if(!pwfile) error_handling 
char pwline [70]; 
fgets (pwline, sizeof pwline, pwfile);
int pwlen = strlen (pwline); 
if(pwlen==0 || pwline[pwlen-1]!='\n') error_handling
pwline[--pwlen] = '\0';

// Open file_name and read into inbuff for flen as you have now 
// Optionally confirm the first 8 bytes are "Salted__"
// If on Windows must fopen with mode "rb" to get all bytes correctly;
// on Unix it is clearer to specify this but not actually needed
// because on Unix binary files and text files are treated the same

unsigned char key [256/8]; // AES-256 key is 32 bytes
unsigned char iv [128/8]; // AES IV is 16 bytes (regardless of key)
EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_md5(), inbuff+8, /* the salt! */
    (unsigned char*)pwline, pwlen, 1, key, iv);

// Now continue as you have with EVP_Encrypt{Init,Update,Final}
// using key,iv except use buffer inbuff+16 for length flen-16 .
// (And do something with the output, which you don't now!)
```

## To create the file you apparently wanted

To use `enc` to create a file encrypted with a direct key, you must pass it with the `-K` option (uppercase K) on the commandline in hex. However, it's a nuisance to handle hex in your C program, so I would handle it on the encrypt side something like:

```
openssl rand 32 >sym.key # AES-256 key must be exactly 32 bytes, not more
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in temp.txt -out temp.enc \
  -K $(od -An -tx1 sym.key | sed 's/ //g') -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

then in your C program read `sym.key` (as binary on Windows at least) and use it as-is, with an IV of 16 0's as you have now.

Alternatively, have `rand` write hex and use that as-is

```
openssl rand -hex 32 >sym.key
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in temp.txt -out temp.enc -K $(cat sym.key) -iv (same)
```

then in your C program read `sym.key` (as a text line) and convert it from 64 chars of hex to `unsigned char key [32]`.

## Other points

If you did need to decode a base64 file, you don't need to read it into memory first then push a b64BIO on a memBIO; you can push a b64BIO on a fileBIO that reads the file.

You don't need to allocate `flen*2` for `outbuff`. Decrypted plaintext will never be longer than the ciphertext. (Which for the salted-PBE form is actually `flen-16` as above.) It is *encryption* that can expand the data, and then only one block (for AES, 16 bytes).

It's good practice to check `malloc` didn't return `NULL` before using it. This rarely happens on modern systems, but it can occur if even simple code like this is called from a larger program and some other part of the program has a bug that exhausts memory, or perhaps a vulnerability exploited by a denial-of-service attack.

If you want to support large files that don't fit in the memory available, or might not, iteratively read chunks, feed each into `DecryptUpdate`, write out the results (which will lag about one block), and at EOF call `DecryptFinal` and output any last partial block.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you for your valuable solutions. This helped me alot. I have tried the above scenarios as you suggested. I have succeeded 98% in decrypting. I'm facing below error with this.
By using **EVP_BytesToKey** this logic (first solution) I'm able to decrypt the file. But additionally it is printing some garbage values.
By using the next approach with **converting hex to unsigned char**. It has decrypted the total file. But it has not printing the first character.
Could you guide me on this.

Comment: @Sai (1) the first method works for me. Are you sure you are using only the valid part of `outbuff` namely `outlen1+outlen2` bytes? Any bytes after that may be garbage leftover from before the buffer was allocated. In particular the decrypted data is NOT followed by a null byte so treating it as a C string with things like `strlen strcpy printf("%s")` or `std::string(outbuff)` is wrong. `std::string(outbuff,outlen1+outlen2)` or `printf("%.*s", outlen1+outlen2, outbuff)` are right. ...

Comment: ... (2) For the second from your very vague description my only guess is that you messed up the IV, which would cause the first byte (or several) of the decrypted text to display wrong and possibly not be visible at all. If that's not it, add a minimal complete example to your question -- and preferably comment also; I *think* I get autonotified for a question edit but I'm not sure and better safe than sorry.

Comment: I got your point Dave. as discussed with my team, we are using **rand write hex** to generate 32 byte key. I'm the the total len **outlen1 + outlen2** into a variable **outdata_len** and then storing the **'\0'** at the end of the outdata as **outdata [outdata_len] = '\0'**.
Now it is getting the proper data without any garbabge value.
I have not tried with 1st scenario as we are comfortable with this.
**Thank you for your valuable suggestion. It was very helpful to me. Thank you so much.**